# How to convert multiple SVG's to one PNG image?

Tags: javascript, svg, png

I need to convert 2 separate SVG's into 1 PNG image. I currently have code working for converting 1 SVG to a PNG. This code is shown below, I convert the SVG to canvas to PNG.

The SVG's are on the same page, and I have tried using an array to iterate through them and grab both. The code I am currently working on is also below, but is not working. Any advice on how to convert the SVGs to the same PNG image?

Thanks a bunch!

**Single SVG to PNG**

```js
// convert svg to png 
function svgToPng(){
    var svg = document.querySelectorAll('svg')[0];
    // clone svg nodes
    var copy = svg.cloneNode(true);
    // convert to xml format for storage/transportation
    var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
    var data = serializer.serializeToString(copy);
    // create url 
    var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window; 
    // create image/blob 
    var img = new Image();
    var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
    var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(blob);
    // create canvas 
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // draw image on canvas
    img.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, $(svg0).width(), $(svg0).height());
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url, url1);
        var imgURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    }
    // send new image to window
    img.src = url;
    // return img.src;
    window.open().document.write('<img src="' + img.src + '" width="1600" height="800"/>');
};
```

**Multiple SVG's to PNG**

```js
// convert multipl svgs to png
function multSvgToPng(){
    var array = [];
    var totalSvg = document.querySelectorAll('svg');  // NodeList(2) [svg, svg]
    // create array 
    for(var i = 0; i < totalSvg.length; i++){
        array = document.querySelectorAll('svg')[i];
    }
    for(var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
        var svg = array[j]; 
        var copy = svg.cloneNode(true);
        var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
        var data = serializer.serializeToString(copy);
        var DOMURL = window.URL || window.webkitURL || window;
        var img = new Image();
        var blob = new Blob([data], {type: "image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8"});
        var url = DOMURL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var svgStr = serializer.serializeToString(copy);
    }
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    img.onload = function(){
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, $(svg).width(), $(svg).height());
        DOMURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        var imgURI = canvas.toDataURL("image/png").replace("image/png", "image/octet-stream");
    }
    // send new image to window
    img.src = url;
    // return img.src;
    window.open().document.write('<img src="' + img.src + '" width="1600" height="800"/>');
}
```

**Example SVG Images**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg> 
 
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Nikki and welcome to SO. Could you include two SVG's in your last snippet for us to try out?

Comment: Hi Emiel, thank you and sure! I included two example SVG's in my question above.

Answer (score 2):

I've used your technique and made two separate functions. The first function `drawSVGToCanvas` creates a canvas for a single SVG, by converting it to a blob and drawing it onto the canvas when the image has loaded. It returns a promise with the canvas element when it is fullfilled.

`convertSVGsToSingleImage` accepts a list of SVG elements for which it will loop over and call `drawSVGToCanvas` for each of those SVG elements. It waits until they are rendered and continues to draw the returned canvas elements on a single new canvas. This is where the combining happens.

```js
const preview = document.getElementById('preview');
const svgs = document.querySelectorAll('svg');

function drawSVGToCanvas(svg) {
  const { width, height } = svg.getBoundingClientRect();
  const serializer = new XMLSerializer();
  const copy = svg.cloneNode(true);
  const data = serializer.serializeToString(copy);
  const image = new Image();
  const blob = new Blob([data], {
    type: 'image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8'
  });
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    image.addEventListener('load', () => {
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
      resolve(canvas);
    }, { once: true });
    image.src = url;
  })
}

async function convertSVGsToSingleImage(svgs, format = 'image/png') {
  const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  const drawSVGs = Array.from(svgs).map(svg => drawSVGToCanvas(svg))
  const renders = await Promise.all(drawSVGs);
  canvas.width = Math.max(...renders.map(render => render.width));
  canvas.height = Math.max(...renders.map(render => render.height));
  renders.forEach(render => ctx.drawImage(render, 0, 0, render.width, render.height));
  const source = canvas.toDataURL(format).replace(format, 'image/octet-stream');
  return source;
}

convertSVGsToSingleImage(svgs).then(source => {
  const image = new Image();
  image.addEventListener('load', () => {
    preview.append(image);
  })
  image.src = source;
});
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="110">
  <rect width="300" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);stroke-width:3;stroke:rgb(0,0,0)" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>

<svg height="100" width="100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" />
  Sorry, your browser does not support inline SVG.  
</svg>

<div id="preview"></div>
```

Comment: `svg.getBBox()` gets you the tight bounding box around the **visible content** of the svg. In other words: it is smaller than the intrinsic size of the SVG, and x and y are not guaranteed to be 0. It is pure luck that your function does not cut off some part of the content.

Comment: I agree. It was an experiment on my end. I've changed it to use `getBoundingClientRect()` which gives a much more expected result.